# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript

On loading the function `getPlatforms` gets called and fills the first dropdown.
Inside this function, i call the function `ClearOptionsFast` for the other 2 drop downs.
However, it gives the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

I saw the page source and indeed the item is present. Whats wrong here?

```
    <select name="label_select" id="label_select">
    </select>
```

```js
function ClearOptionsFast(id) {
  alert("func");
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
}
async function getPlatforms() {
  const response = await fetch(
    'http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_platforms', {
      method: 'POST',
    }
  );
  const jdata = await response.json();
  ldata = jdata["final_result"]
  var selectElement = document.getElementById('device_select');
  selectElement.appendChild(new Option("SELECT", "SELECT")).cloneNode(true)
  for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
    selectElement.appendChild(new Option(ldata[i], ldata[i])).cloneNode(true)
  }
  ClearOptionsFast(document.getElementById("label_select"))
  ClearOptionsFast(document.getElementById("baseline_select"))
}
window.onload = getPlatforms;

async function getLabels(device) {
  var response = await fetch(
    'http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_labels', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "device": device
      })
    }
  );
  var jdata = await response.json();
  ldata = jdata["final_result"]
  var selectElement = document.getElementById('label_select');
  selectElement.appendChild(new Option("SELECT", "SELECT")).cloneNode(true)
  for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
    selectElement.appendChild(new Option(ldata[i], ldata[i])).cloneNode(true)
  }
}

async function getBaselines(device) {
  var response = await fetch(
    'http://10.64.127.94:5000/api/get_baselines', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "device": device
      })
    }
  );
  var jdata = await response.json();
  ldata = jdata["final_result"]
  var selectElement = document.getElementById('baseline_select');
  selectElement.appendChild(new Option("SELECT", "SELECT")).cloneNode(true)
  for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
    selectElement.appendChild(new Option(ldata[i], ldata[i])).cloneNode(true)
  }
}

function getLabelsBaselines(device) {
  getLabels(device);
  getBaselines(device);
}

function selects() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('chk');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox')
      ele[i].checked = true;
  }
}

function deSelect() {
  var ele = document.getElementsByName('chk');
  for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    if (ele[i].type == 'checkbox')
      ele[i].checked = false;
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Unified Performance Heat Map</h1>
<hr>
<form name="device_form" id="device_form">
  <label>Choose a device:</label>
  <select name="device_select" id="device_select" onchange="getLabelsBaselines(this.value);">
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<label>Select the label:</label>
<select name="label_select" id="label_select">
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Select the baseline:</label>
<select name="baseline_select" id="baseline_select">
</select>
<br>
<br>
<label>Select the features:</label>
<br>

<br>
<input type="button" onclick='selects()' value="Select All" />
<input type="button" onclick='deSelect()' value="Deselect All" />

<br>
<br>
<button type="button">Make Heat Map !</button>
<hr>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>FEATURE</td>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center;">IPSEC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PACKET</td>
    <td>64</td>
    <td>IMIX</td>
    <td>1400</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BASE</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LABEL</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HEATMAP</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ClearOptionsFast` function expects an `id` as a `string` for the first argument, which it will use to do `getElementById(id)`. However you're passing it an `Element` (instead of a `string`) because you're *already* calling `getElementById` before the function.

For example

```js
ClearOptionsFast(document.getElementById("label_select"))
```

should be

```js
ClearOptionsFast("label_select")
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised my mistake. Now I am not seeing the error, however, for some reason the drop downs are not clearing. Can you help on that pls?

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearOptionsFast(document.getElementById("label_select"))
ClearOptionsFast(document.getElementById("baseline_select"))
```

These two lines seem to be wrong, I think you mean to do this?

```
ClearOptionsFast("label_select")
ClearOptionsFast("baseline_select")
```

Because you are trying to send the name of an 'id' to the function ClearOptionsFast

```
function ClearOptionsFast(id)
            {
                alert("func");
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "";
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, I realised my mistake. Now I am not seeing the error, however, for some reason the drop downs are not clearing. Can you help on that pls?

Comment: @AkshayJ Please mark my answer as correct so that others can also realize the error.